# How to fix Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19 in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

In my application i want get data from server, for get connect to server i used **Retrofit**, **OkHttp**.
But when running application, show me force close error.
In android **api 21+** is not error, but below **api 21** show me force close error.

**ApiClient class codes:**

```
class ApiClient constructor(private val deviceUUID: String) {

    private val apiServices: ApiServices

    init {
        //Gson
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        //Http log
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level =
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE

        //Http Builder
        val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        clientBuilder.interceptors().add(loggingInterceptor)
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            request.newBuilder().addHeader(AGENT_NAME, AGENT_VALUE).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            request.newBuilder().addHeader(X_CLIENT_VERSION, APP_VERSION_NAME).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            request.newBuilder().addHeader(UUID_NAME, deviceUUID).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }

        //Http client
        val client = clientBuilder
            .readTimeout(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build()

        //Retrofit
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()

        //Init apiServices
        apiServices = retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java)
    }

    companion object {
        private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null

        fun getInstance(deviceUUID: String): ApiClient =
            apiClient ?: synchronized(this) {
                apiClient ?: ApiClient(deviceUUID).also {
                    apiClient = it
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Send apiServices to ApisUseCase for initialize all of apis
     */
    fun apisUseCase(): ApisUseCase {
        return ApisUseCase(apiServices)
    }
}
```

Show me error for this line : `.build()` on this method `val client = clientBuilder`

I added this codes into **gradle.build**

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

but again show me error!

**Error message :**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1015)
    at com.app.android.data.services.ApiClient.<init>(ApiClient.kt:56)
    at com.app.android.ui.splash.SplashPresenterImpl.checkUpdate(SplashPresenterImpl.kt:18)
    at com.app.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.java:238)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findPlatform(Platform.java:202)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:79)
```

**Gradle.Build codes:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 100
        versionName "2.5.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //JWT decoder
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.2.0'
    //Anko lib
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.8"
    //Rx
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8"
    //OkHttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.0"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0"
    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    //Image
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //Calligraphy
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.0'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:1.0.0'
    //Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05'
    //Preferences lib
    implementation 'com.github.MrNouri:GoodPrefs:1.0'
    //Multiple sizes
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    // OnBoarding
    implementation 'com.codemybrainsout.onboarding:onboarder:1.0.4'
    //Alerter
    implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:4.0.2'
    //Fabric answer
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.7@aar') { transitive = true }
    //Fabric crash
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') { transitive = true }
    //Adjust
    implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.17.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    //Google and firebase services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    //Support MultiDex
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    //Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
    //Android svg and noneOldAndroid
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.3'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    //Animations
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

For minSDK lower than 21, change your OkHttp version to 3.12.12 in gradle like this -

```
  //OkHttp
  implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12"){
      force = true //API 19 support
  }
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.12'
```

It should work fine!

Comment: sorry, 4.4. fail

Comment: 3.12.5 is latest version as september 2019

Comment: You can find the latest 3.12.x version here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp

Comment: New gradle syntax: `implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp') { version { strictly '3.12.12'  } }`

Comment: for me getting the same error after the updated os 11 (Pixel 4), anyone tested android os 11? I will try  ket you guys know

Comment: @Matt No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types:

Comment: `force = true` is deprecated. Use `MutableVersionConstraint#strictly(String)` instead

Comment: when use this code get Exception =>ExceptionInInitializerError

Answer (score 10):

OKHTTP just dropped support for Android 4

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4481

You must use an older version or maybe a sperate branch for your app.

See this Medium post from Jessie Wilson for more info:
https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5-818bb78d07ce

Comment: Worked for me. Appreciate the links to be confident with the decision. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For everyone who still need the library for older version of Android, you need to use the OkHttp 3.12.x branch. The latest release from the branch is [3.12.6](https://github.com/square/okhttp/releases/tag/parent-3.12.6). I've tested and confirmed the version worked on Samsung Tablet SM-T116NU (Android 19).

Here's the excerpt from OkHttp:

> The OkHttp 3.12.x branch supports Android 2.3+ (API level 9+) and Java 7+. These platforms lack support for TLS 1.2 and should not be used. But because upgrading is difficult we will backport critical fixes to the 3.12.x branch through December 31, 2020.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Okhttp documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/#requirements), they dropped the support for Android 4.

The solution is to use the 3.12.x versions of Okhttp:

```
def okhttp_version="3.12.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp") {
    version { strictly "$okhttp_version" }
}
```

You can also read about the reason for this change in [Square blog](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5/):

> Why Android 5+ and Why Now?
>
> TLS is the mechanism that makes HTTPS calls secure, private, and
> authenticated. OkHttp is aware of five versions: SSLv3 (1996), TLSv1
> (1999), TLSv1.1 (2006), TLSv1.2 (2008), and TLSv1.3 (2018). We dropped
> support for SSLv3 in 2014 in response to the POODLE attack.
>
> Now it’s time to drop both TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 and to make TLSv1.2 the
> Internet’s new minimum standard. On October 15 our colleagues at
> Google, Mozilla, Microsoft, and Apple announced that their browsers
> will require TLSv1.2 or better starting in early 2020.
>
> Google added support for TLSv1.2 in Android 5.0. Oracle added it in
> Java 8. In OkHttp 3.13 we require that the host platform has built-in
> support for TLSv1.2.
>
> What about Android 4.x?
>
> Google’s distribution dashboard shows that ~11% of the devices that
> visited the Play Store in October 2018 were running Android 4.x. We’ve
> created a branch, OkHttp 3.12.x, to support these devices. Should we
> encounter any severe bugs or security problems we’ll backport the
> fixes and release. We plan to maintain this branch through December
> 31, 2020.
>
> If you really need TLSv1.2 on Android 4.x, that’s possible! Ankush
> Gupta has written a thorough guide that explains how to get Google
> Play Services to do it. Even if you follow this process you should
> still use OkHttp 3.12.x with Android 4.x devices.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/5773044/anupam
This code works in Android API 19:

```
// Note: 3.12.+ to support Android API 19
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.10'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.10'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.6.4'
testImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.6.4'
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.6.4'
```

Comment: really appreciate this, since okhttp usually used with retrofit, it's good thing to know which retrofit version works with which okhttp version

Answer (score 3):

Note for @Anupam answer - force is deprecated if you are using Android Studio 4.0+

> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html
>
> Forced dependencies
>   Forcing dependency versions using force = true on a first-level dependency has been deprecated.
>
> Force has both a semantic and ordering issue which can be avoided by using a strict [version constraint.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#rich-version-constraints)

the way ahead is to use the keyword "strictly" for dependency downgrade.
refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version

So you should end up with some thing like the following...

```
  implementation ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp'){ 
            version {
                strictly '3.12.12'
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in API level 19 when I added below in build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.13.1'
```

Finally, The Below Code helped me to fix that issue:

```
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

Hope this solution works well for all.

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.4 (works for me)

```
def ok_http_version = "3.11.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$ok_http_version"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$ok_http_version"
```

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.x?

Google’s distribution dashboard shows that ~11% of the devices that visited the Play Store in October 2018 were running Android 4.x. We’ve created a branch, OkHttp 3.12.x, to support these devices. Should we encounter any severe bugs or security problems we’ll backport the fixes and release. We plan to maintain this branch through December 31, 2020.

If you really need TLSv1.2 on Android 4.x, that’s possible! Ankush Gupta has written a thorough guide that explains how to get Google Play Services to do it. Even if you follow this process you should still use OkHttp 3.12.x with Android 4.x devices.

so you can use below code and resolve your problem

```
  implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12"){
  force = true //API 19 support
  }
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.12'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use version 3.11.0 for api level below 21

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the new Android Studio Gradle syntax, you can do

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.12'
implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12') {
    // force support to old android api 19
    version { strictly '3.12.12' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For gradle.kts:

```
// 3.12.13 - last version with API 19 support (Android 4.4)
val okHttpVersion = "3.12.13"
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp") {
    version { strictly(okHttpVersion) }
}
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion")
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okHttpVersion")
```

Answer (score -2):

Here I solve that problem downgrading this dependencies to this versions

```
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
```

And adding this code into onCreate of MainActivity

```
try {
      ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
      // Indicates that Google Play services is out of date, disabled, etc.
      // Prompt the user to install/update/enable Google Play services.
      GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
        .showErrorNotification(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode());

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
      // Indicates a non-recoverable error; the ProviderInstaller is not able
      // to install an up-to-date Provider.
    }
```

Downgrade dependencies is neet because newest version need android API 21 or later.

That code above is to android update your security provider to protect against SSL exploits. See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html to know more about it.

Comment: There is an article cited by the Square blog about it: https://medium.com/tech-quizlet/working-with-tls-1-2-on-android-4-4-and-lower-f4f5205629a