# Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19 while using Retrofit 2, OkHttp3

Tags: java, android, sdk, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using **Retrofit 2 and OkHttp3** to data from server and I get 
error while using **Min_SDK 17** and my device's API is **17** also

I tried this answer :[How to fix Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818660/how-to-fix-expected-android-api-level-21-but-was-19-in-android)

Also I tried this answer https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4597#issuecomment-461204144

but I get the same error .

**my Gradle.Build class**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "some"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility = "8"
    sourceCompatibility = "8"
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
}
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.11.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0"
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'net.alhazmy13.hijridatepicker:library:2.0.2'
implementation group: 'com.github.msarhan', name: 'ummalqura-calendar', version: '1.1.9'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.jaiselrahman:FilePicker:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0'

        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
   }
```

**my API Client**

```
    public class APIClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

public static Retrofit getInstanceRetrofit(){

    if(okHttpClient==null) {
        initOkHttp();
    }
    if(retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Const.URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
        return retrofit;

}

  private static void initOkHttp() {
    int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 60;
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    okHttpClient = httpClient.build();
}
  }
```

**my Logs**

```
    1-03 06:09:07.850 2827-2827/some
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: some, PID: 2827
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:296)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:262)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:235)
    at some.Network.APIClient.initOkHttp(APIClient.java:40)
    at some.Network.APIClient.getInstanceRetrofit(APIClient.java:25)
    at some.MvpImplementation.DropdownImpInteractor.getDropdowns(DropdownImpInteractor.java:18)
    at some.MvpImplementation.DropdownImpPresenter.requestDropdowns(DropdownImpPresenter.java:21)
    at some.Views.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:87)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 19
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.java:238)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findPlatform(Platform.java:202)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:79)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:296) 
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:262) 
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:235) 
    at some.Network.APIClient.initOkHttp(APIClient.java:40) 
    at some.Network.APIClient.getInstanceRetrofit(APIClient.java:25) 
    at some.MvpImplementation.DropdownImpInteractor.getDropdowns(DropdownImpInteractor.java:18) 
    at some.MvpImplementation.DropdownImpPresenter.requestDropdowns(DropdownImpPresenter.java:21) 
    at some.Views.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:87) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use a lower version of retrofit

Comment: @AliSh No , see the correct answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have added `OkHttp` dependency twice.

In your `build.gradle` you have:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0"
    ...
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1"
}
```

Starting with version 3.13.0 they removed support for Android < 5. 
You just need to delete the

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1"
```

line and it should work fine

Comment: nicely spotted :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you guys have still crash on `Android 4.0 and above`, here is quick solution:

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1")

implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.8") {
force = true
}

implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.8"
```

Above code tested and verified on `Android 4.4`
Thanks

Comment: getting below error : javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb9570410: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x8d9f3990:0x00000000)

Comment: `force = true` is deprecated. Use `MutableVersionConstraint#strictly(String)` instead

Answer (score 2):

In your gradle file you have:

`implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0"`

The docs say:

https://square.github.io/okhttp/

> OkHttp works on Android 5.0+ (API level 21+) and on Java 8+.

The OkHttp 3.12.x branch supports Android 2.3+ (API level 9+) and Java 7+. These platforms lack support for TLS 1.2 and should not be used. But because upgrading is difficult we will backport critical fixes to the 3.12.x branch through December 31, 2020.

So you could try:

`implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I solved it by @MatPag Answer