# Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30

Tags: android, okhttp

How is it possible that I get this message? It does not make any sense.
I'm using `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0`

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$Companion.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.kt:370)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findPlatform(Platform.kt:204)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.access$findPlatform(Platform.kt:178)
    2020-09-16 12:37:07.645 6480-6480/lv.ltt.gasogmp.dev_v3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at 
    okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.kt:179)
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818660/how-to-fix-expected-android-api-level-21-but-was-19-in-android

Comment: That question is about when SDK INT is actually below 21. But i have SDK INT 30 ! @RAINA

Comment: It also works with SDK 28

Comment: @Oridedles may be  the Library has not add its support to SDK 30 yet..I am not sure .Cant you downgrade and check the latest SDK version it works? and try to  continue with that may be

Comment: Add an explicit dependency on OkHttp 4.9.0.

Comment: @JesseWilson yes sure i could do that, anyway they should improve exception message because it is not entirely correct and confusing

Comment: The bug has been fixed a while ago, but because you are on an older version you got hit by it still. Generally OkHttp does a lot of work to hide the platform differences for a lot of different platforms and versions. When these change, we need to update the checks we use and rely on client upgrading to get the newest detection logic.

Comment: Have a similar problem with 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'. It looks like the library doesn't support API 30.

Comment: I had this problem too and @JesseWilson your comment solved it, you should make it an answer to the question so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Add an explicit dependency on OkHttp 4.9.0. Or whatever is newest at the time you read this.

This bug is embarrassing but it's been fixed for so long that you shouldn’t be encountering it in new code.

Comment: Fixed for me. I also had to update some okio usages (access 'source' and 'buffed' directly instead of calling their methods)

Comment: FYI, latest is 4.9.1. Look here for the latest at the time of reading this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp

Comment: Also, for anybody still using version 3.x of OkHttp, updating to 3.14.7 or higher resolves the error, see this changelog entry: https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3147 (Latest version at time of writing is 3.14.9)

Comment: I used implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11". But I am still experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 65):

Just Add the Dependency `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'`

PS - Check the latest version here before you add the dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp

Comment: thanks man .. I spend lot of time in finding problem because my app was not working for android 11 .. thankyou once again

Answer (score 3):

Add `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'` inside `android\app\build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ........
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'   
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2' 
    ..........
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrage Okhttp3 or retrofit version**

> *Latest Okhttp3 version is 4.9.2*
> *Latest Retrofit version is 2.9.0*

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2' 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
```